# JPA Map User Types with Wrapper Classes

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, jpa-2.0

How can I map and change the fields that are actually wrapped classes.

```
private UserId uid = new UserId();
```

Where UserId is a **class wrapped inside many classes**. It takes string as Id **but its equivalent field in database is long**.

When I annotate it JPA complains about type and accessibility of the fields.

I need to tell JPA **using annotations**

1. How to access actual fields that would be mapped eventually
2. Obviously it does not know how to convert it from string to long, How to do it?

I am new to JPA and Java and using annotations on fields.

Thanks

Here is the code

**UserId.java**

```
public class UserId extends CustomString {
public UserId(String value) {
    super(value);
}
```

**CustomString.java**

```
public abstract class CustomString extends ParentDomain {

private String value;

public CustomString(String value) {
    if (value == null) {
        throw new NullStringException(this.getClass().getName());
    }
    this.value = value;
}
//Getters and Setters
@Override
public String toString() {
    return this.value;
}
```

}

**ParentDomain.java**

```
public abstract class ParentDomain {
// nothing
```

}

**What I have done so far**

I have created getter setters with Long return type after converting from Long to string I return the value.

Comment: We need to see some more code I think, like how does UserId class look like?

Comment: JPA provides AttributeConverter so you can map any type. So what is the problem using that?

Comment: @NeilStockton Thanks for the comment. I would try to create one. I didt knew about such thing.

Comment: @omega_cancer Note that it only exists from JPA 2.1 so check which you're using

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can write a [Hibernate UserType](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.3/manual/en-US/html/ch06.html#types-custom-ut) that takes the UserId object and maps it to a LONG column.